# Password on Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-8, login

I have an Acer Iconic tablet running Windows 8. Initially there was no password requirement on the welcome screen. I've never needed a password right through my history of PC use from Windows 3.11 (c.1994). However, I succumbed and opened a Microsoft Account. Thereafter I've had to enter a password every time I start or restart the machine. I don't need and don't want a password as I won't be buying any apps or services from Microsoft. I tried to follow their text Help to reverse things but couldn't work out what to click, tick or tap! I then went to MS online help chat. The person was very helpful but in doing what she suggested we were disconnected and I can't get back to her. Surely there must be some easy way to undo the p/w requirement with a few swipes, taps, clicks or key presses.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate issues here:

1. You don't need to use a MS account to login into Windows 8. You can use a standard Windows account. Microsoft has a guide [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-user-account) to setting up a standard account.
2. To automatically login follow the steps from this [guide](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/16/windows-8-how-to-automatically-log-on/) or others on the web.